# can't use css on .scroll-content because it breaks ion-infinite-scroll

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

The first image below shows the unwanted whitespace that is being created by an excessively large `margin-top` on `.scroll-content`. I countered this by putting `margin-top: -47%` on `.scroll-content`. However, doing this broke my `ion-infinite-scroll` on the page. It seems that any and all css that I put on `.scroll-content` breaks `ion-infinite-scroll`.

If you click on the images to look closer. You can see in the devtools `Elements` section that the `margin-top` is being created dynamically somewhere as it is added as an `inline` style. Does anyone know any tricks for how to either move the whole `.scroll-content` up or how to negate the `margin-top`? I don't really have any css to show for this...I am just trying to override an element's style that is created by `ionic`. Again, any css that I use on `.scroll-content` breaks `ion-infinite-scroll` so this needs to be done in a really hacky way (yay css).

Also, changing it dynamically with `setElementStyle` or something like `setAttribute('style', 'margin-top: 132px')` breaks `.ion-infinite-scroll`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I made my own bottom-of-the-screen-when-scrolling detector:

```
let element = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.scroll-content');
element.addEventListener('scroll', (event) =>
{
    var element = event.target;
    if (element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight)
    {
         ... loading new items code goes here ...
```